# Live streaming solution

Tags: flash, streaming, live

I am searching for a streaming solution, my company need to record and stream a live event on a Website, I am looking for hint as to which technology we should use, and what do we need in our setup.

This is how I see that for now :

We will need to install 3 camera, 1 console (to manage which camera is streamed), 1 Streaming server, on the location of the events. And our website would have a plugin (Flash?) showing what is streaming by the Server at the event location.

Do I have that right?

Any of you have any experience with similar technology?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest solution would be to connect your console to a unit like [VSiCaster](http://netromedia.com/services/streaming-hardware-encoders.aspx), which is already pre-configured to stream to a CDN (in this case [NetroMedia](http://www.netromedia.com)). You then get a Flash embed code to put on your website. Because the output is H.264/AAC over RTSP, you can view the stream in the iPhone, BlackBerry, and other smart-phones ([see example](http://netromedia.com/examples/vsicaster-example.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

[Red5](http://www.red5.org/) is an Open Source Flash Server.